# how to add system libs in the android-maven-plugin dex phase?

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

If I use system scope to inlcude jars, the console shows that the android-maven-plugin:dex phase,there are no jars in the command line. but if I use maven repository to include jars, the console shows the jars in the dex command. Why? who can help me if I want to include the jars parameters in the dex command line when i use system scope jars in the pom.xml?

Comment: Why do you want to use the system scope for those JARs?

Comment: These jars are stored in SVN not in Maven repositories,so, developers will change the jars and the pom.xml will not know that change,we have to install the new jar into maven repositories manually. if we use System scope, the Jenkins(our CI server) will checkout the codes and jars, in this time, the pom.xml needn't to be changed.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to sidestep Maven's build process for some dependencies. So, two supplementary questions: 1. How do you set up the `systemPath` for those dependencies? 2. How does Jenkins go about including those JARs in the runtime environment of your apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yep all artifacts scoped as system excluded from dex process by line:

```
    /**
     * Which dependency scopes should not be included when unpacking dependencies into the apk.
     */
    protected static final List EXCLUDED_DEPENDENCY_SCOPES = Arrays.asList( "provided", "system", "import" );
```

See AbstractAndroidMojo.java in version 3.8.0

Comment: I was looking at a related problem and found that, as of about 2 years ago, this plugin does actually include system scope deps again.